# C2061 error: 'identifier', but I included the header?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, syntax-error

I am working on a VC++ project (nothing Visual just using Visual Studio for editing). And in one of my classes i have a bunch of C2061 errors apearing, but evreything is fine, i double and triple checked.
this is the class where the errors occur:
Circle.h:

```
#ifndef __SGE__Circle__
#define __SGE__Circle__
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "Vector2.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
class Circle
{
public:
    Circle();
    Circle(float xCenter, float yCenter, float radius);
    Circle(Vector2& center, float radius);
    ~Circle();
    bool Contains(Vector2& point);
    bool Contains(Rectangle& rectangle); //ERROR OCCURS HERE
    bool Contains(Circle& circle);
    bool isContained(Rectangle& rectangle); //ERROR OCCURS HERE
    bool Intersects(Rectangle& rectangle); //ERROR OCCURS HERE
    bool Intersects(Circle& circle); 
    float Radius;
    Vector2 Center;
};
#endif
```

the error are like this :error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Rectangle'
and they apear everywhere Rectangle is called

Rectangle class looks like this:

Rectangle.h:

```
#ifndef __SGE__Rectangle__
#define __SGE__Rectangle__
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "Vector2.h"
class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle();
    Rectangle(float x, float y, float width, float height);
    Rectangle(Vector2& position, Vector2& size);
    ~Rectangle();
    Vector2* getCorners();
    Vector2 getCenter();
    bool Contains(Vector2& point);
    bool Contains(Rectangle& rectangle);
    bool Intersects(Rectangle& rectangle);
    float X;
    float Y;
    float Width;
    float Height;
};
#endif
```

And i also import both Circle.h and Rectangle.h in my main.cpp

and for fun :)
Vector2.h:

```
#ifndef _SGE_Vector2_
#define _SGE_Vector2_
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <math.h>
class Vector2
{
public:
    Vector2();
    Vector2(float x, float y);
    bool operator == (const Vector2& a);
    bool operator != (const Vector2& a);
    Vector2 operator +(const Vector2& a);
    Vector2 operator +=(const Vector2& a);
    Vector2 operator -(const Vector2& a);
    Vector2 operator -=(const Vector2& a);
    Vector2 operator *(const float a);
    Vector2 operator *=(const float a);
    Vector2 operator /(const float a);
    Vector2 operator /=(const float a);
    float Length();
    void Normalize();
    ~Vector2();
    GLfloat X;
    GLfloat Y;
};
#endif
```

Comment: Wall of code! Could you extract a [minimal reproducing example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) out of it, please?

Comment: What line of code does this error points to? You posted a lot of code which make it hard for us to figure out the solution.

Comment: [OT]: names with double underscore (as `__SGE__Circle__`) is reserved.

Comment: Just for fun, add the content of `Vector2.h` to the code wall.

Comment: modiffing names with double underscore did't work

Comment: the errors apear in circle.h at lines 15, 17, 18

Comment: Using lowercase and uppercase with the same name is not a good idea for variable names

Comment: BTW, you may use forward declaration instead of direct include in header.

Comment: tryed forward declaration right before posting this i got a biger bunch of errors:-D. thanks for the advice anyway

Comment: changed the name of the rectangle variables to bounds, no result!

Comment: also tryed to recopy the entire project recreating every file and copypasting the code from the original, errors stil occur :(

Comment: Have you tried without `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` since you don't seem to need it in the files you've shown.  Perhaps there's a conflicting symbol or a macro causing the issue.

Comment: @PinteLaurentiu I moved the three files you included into one file and it compiled after defining dummy functions (since you dont have the .cpp files).  This definitely looks to be an inclusion problem, and would play with your inclusion guards.

Comment: I tried your code without GLFS/glfw3.h included, replaced GLFloat in Vector2.h with float and things work okay. Other thing would be to put all your classes in a different namespace

Comment: @PinteLaurentiu Jarod42's suggestion of forward declaring would also potentially solve your problem.

Comment: Sarang you are right just after reading your comment i tried the same thing and it work, it seems that GLFW/glfw3.h also contains a function bool Rectangle(...); so i reincluded GLFW/glfw3.h and replace Rectangle with Rect in my entire project, my other question is can i "override" the Rectangle function with my Rectangle class because i'm quite sure i won't need that function and Rect just doesn't sound right.

Comment: @PinteLaurentiu: what you should do is put your classes in namespace. Say something like Math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "GLFW/glfw3.h" contains a function: bool Rectangle(...); which creates errors when class Rectangle is used.
   There are 2 solution for this problem:

1. Rename class Rectangle to something else ex: Rect
2. Create a namespace that contains all the classes making posible to call

`using namespace X; //X is replaced by the name of your namespace`

in main overriding the Rectangle function with the Rectangle class .

The problem was solved with Sarang's help!